# How do I configure a reverse proxy for my dockers containers?

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, reverse-proxy

I'm currently configuring my raspberry pi as my personal home server and I want to use docker. I have few different containers :

-**Apache/PHP** 81:80

-**Nextcloud** 8080:80

-**Minecraft** 25565:25565

I already have a dynamic domaim (http://felixbestwaifu.hopto.org)

When I try to access felixbestwaifu.hopto.org:8080, it timeouts :c

**My goal**

Nextcloud

- cloud.hostname.org
- or hostname.org/nextcloud

Website

- Domain.org
- Domain.org/about.php
- Domain.org/Anime.php

I tried using NGINX by creating a **nextcloud.conf** in **/sites-enabled/** and **/sites-available/**, but it didn't work at all ^^'

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name nextcloud;

    location /nextcloud {
        proxy_pass 192.168.2.150:8080/;
    }
}
```

*Note : 192.168.2.150 is my pi static IP in my network*

So here is my question : How do you set-up a reverse proxy for docker containers ?

I would really appreciate your help >//< (sorry for bad English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us suppose your Apache-PHP container is called `apache_php`. You should have two `.conf` files there with similar contents (less or more is regarding what you need in your conf files).

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/minecraft.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName minecraft.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@minecraft
        DocumentRoot /home/minecraft
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass "/" "http://minecraft:25565/"
        ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://minecraft:25565/"
        ProxyRequests Off

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/nextcloud.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName nextcloud.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@nextcloud
        DocumentRoot /home/nextcloud
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass "/" "http://nextcloud:8080/"
        ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://nextcloud:8080/"
        ProxyRequests Off

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**Note the trailing `/` in `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse`. If you do not add them, final URLs will be something like `http://minecraft:25565your_page`, while with trailing `/` it will be `http://minecraft:25565/your_page`.**

In this case if anyone enters minecraft.com, your Apache proxies him to **minecraft** site and **minecraft* is only accessible by your Apache container.

**Note that `minecraft.com` and `minecraft` are two different websites in a network called `proxy` that I talk about it below**

**This is what I do in my container, but let me explain it up to my knowledge:**

Suppose Your Apache, your Nextcloud and Minecraft are in the same [network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) (in this case you should create a network, in my case it's called `proxy` network) and all of these three containers should see each other by pinging.

**How your `docker-compose.yml` file should look like in this case**:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
    apache_php:
        build: .
        restart: always
        ports:
           - "81:80"
    minecraft:
        build: .
        restart: always
        ports:
           - "25565:25565"
    nextcloud:
        build: .
        restart: always
        ports:
           - "8080:80"
networks:
default:
external:
  name: proxy
volumes:
db_data: {}
```

So in this file, I'm creating three images called `apache_php`, `minecraft` and `nextcloud` that is built via `Dockerfile` via `build` keyword. I also proxy ports 81 to 80, port 25565 to 25565 and port 8080 to 80.

Then you can create a `Dockerfile` or modify existing one with similar contents:

```
FROM your_os_base:tag

COPY minecraft.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/
COPY nextcloud.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/
COPY my_bash_commands.sh /root/
RUN chmod +x /root/my_bash_commands.sh
RUN /root/my_bash_commands.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["your_thing"]
```

Now what is `my_bash_commands.sh` in my case? As default shell is `sh` in most cases, I create a `bash` file so that I get my desired results.

The `my_bash_commands.sh` is similar to this:

```
#!/usr/bash

service apache2 start
a2ensite minecraft
a2ensite nextcloud
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
service apache2 restart
```

Now you can create them by running `docker-compose up -d` if you are in the path where `docker-compose.yml` is, else you should use `docker-compose -f /absolute_patht_to/docker-compose.yml up -d`.

Comment: thanks you ^-^ ! Sorry for late reply, but it works now :D !